# Rate constants for water exchange

Tags: kinetics, coordination-compounds, reference-request

Are rate constants for water exchange of transition metal aqua-complexes tabulated anywhere ? I haven't been able to find a resource which is anywhere near comprehensive.

Comment: I think [this part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordination_complex#Reactivity) of Wikipedia article touches this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, see Fig. 1 and tables VI-VIII of  [SOLVENT EXCHANGE ON METAL IONS](http://www.researchgate.net/profile/Lothar_Helm/publication/37429092_Solvent_exchange_on_metal_ions/links/5437daec0cf2027cbb204fc0.pdf) Advances in Inorganic Chemistry volume 54 pages 1-69.

Values vary over almost 20 orders of magnitude.

To make this not a link-only answer, roughly, per second exchange rates are:

$\ce{Ir^3+}$  $10^{-10}$

$\ce{Rh^3+}$  $2.2 \times 10^{-9}$

$\ce{Cr^3+}$ $10^{-6}$

$\ce{Ru^3+}$ $10^{-5}$

$\ce{Pt^2+}$ $10^{-3}$

$\ce{Ru^2+}$ $10^{-2}$

$\ce{V^2+}$, $\ce{Fe^3+}$ $10^2$

$\ce{Pd^2+}$, $\ce{V^3+}$ $10^3$

$\ce{Ni^2+}$ $10^4$

$\ce{Ti^3+}$ $10^5$

$\ce{Co^2+}$ $3.2 \times 10^6$

$\ce{Fe^2+}$ $4.4 \times 10^6$

$\ce{Mn^2+}$,  $2.1 \times 10^7$

$\ce{Zn^2+}$ great uncertainty $5 \times 10^7 - 10^{10}$

$\ce{Cd^2+}$ $10^8$

$\ce{Cr^2+}$, $\ce{Hg^2+}$ $10^9$

$\ce{Cu^2+}$ $5.7 \times 10^9$